# How to resolve Duplicate Symbol Error?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker

I'm compiling 2 C++ files together. 4 if you include the header files. The problem is, I keep getting "Duplicate Symbol" errors when the linker tries to link the files together.

Here are my files.

---

**main.h**

```
int test2();
```

---

**main.cc**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "test.h"

int test2(int test) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    test2(test());
    return 0;
}
```

---

**test.h**

```
int hello = 10;
int test();
```

---

**test.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int test() {
  cout << hello << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

I think I'm doing something simple wrong. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.
Here's how I'm compiling the files.

```
c++ main.cc test.cc -o main
```

Here's the error I get:

```
duplicate symbol _hello in:
/var/folders/nj/568_95bj4dg9v11l_mksv_2m0000gn/T/main-3becdd.o
/var/folders/nj/568_95bj4dg9v11l_mksv_2m0000gn/T/test-e84473.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Change `int test2();` to `int test();` in your `main.h` header too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In header file, declare the variable:

```
extern int hello;
```

In exactly one source file, define the variable:

```
int hello = 10;
```

Do not define variables in headers - that's equivalent to defining them in every source file that includes the header, and that's what's causing your linker error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define hello as a "static" (global) variable

```
static int hello = 10;
```

More information is mentioned in a similar question:

[Duplicate symbols while linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431268/duplicate-symbols-while-linking)